# Subscribe to a particular topic with a reactive java WebSocket client

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, java-websocket

is there any way to subscribe to the particular topic using `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` or any other reactive WebSocket client?
Non-reactive WebSocket implementation in Spring has `WebSocketStompClient` that has it own `StompSession` and provides such a functionality, but i can't find something similar for the reactive client.

Comment: StompSession has nothing to do with topics

Comment: @ThomasAndolf but is there any way to connect to the particular topic with a reactive websocket client?